# How to get Owl Carousel Owl-Page (dots) Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

http://prntscr.com/84291c This is what I am trying to get responsive. I'm trying by using media queries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page + .owl-page
    }
}
```

I have tried putting this code in both my css page and the owl.theme.css

Another thing I have tried is putting it in a wrapper like this in my html and then use media query on it. Neither was successful. How can I get it responsive so that the dots dissappear when viewed on mobile?

```
<div class='dot-wrapper'>
  <div class='owl-controls'>
    <div class='owl-pagination'>
        <div class='owl-page'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly, `OwlCarousel` is already responsive, anyway please create a `JSFiddle` , that will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 @media all and (max-width: 658px) { // for mobile devices

   .dots { display:none; } // this is just an example, you can change dots with your own tags

 }
```